# How to implement Video and/or Audio calling in React Native Expo application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webrtc, expo

I am building a react native application using [Expo](https://expo.io/) and i need to add audio calling and video calling functionalities, however it seems that i cant use `react-native-webrtc` (Link [here](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc)) without ejecting Expo.

My question is there anyway i can add audio and video functionality to my application without ejecting Expo, if so how?

If it is of any help knowing what my stack is, as follows:

**Frontend:**

1. React Native
2. Expo
3. Redux
4. SocketIO

**Backend**

1. NodeJS
2. Express
3. SocketIO
4. MongoDB

Thank you very much in advance!

---

### Edit

What am looking for is a way to implement it without relaying on any paid services such as [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/) or [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)

Your help is much appreciated, i have checked the expo voting poll for next features and webrtc is there, hopefully they implement it soon. so in the meantime any other approach to solving this is really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check another solutions  like Ionic React with Cordova or Progressive Web Apps: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/overview

Comment: Thanks for the response but how exactly will ionic solve my issue?

Comment: It's pure web with mobile ux and ui and with  what you need for frontend requirements .

Comment: I guess I'd have to use webrtc in a webview.

Comment: Thanks @diogenesgg for the response but can you elaborate on what you mean exactly

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @Dan no not really, i am still stuck at this. did quite abit of research but in vein. am hoping expo adds webrtc to its API's soon other than that nothing yet. if you come across something please share it! thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I need to integrate video calling feature with my expo project.

Comment: Hello @DivyaniSingh sadly no, i did not find a way to get around this. when i do i will be sure to update this. Let me know if you find something too please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now as of [SDK 42](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-42-579aee2348b6), Expo added the `custom development clients` which pretty much allows you to add any native react native library to your project so working with traditional [webrtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for the ZegoCloud for streaming it support the all mobile language like React native and Flutter it provide you the all sdk also.